# why is jquery.cookie.js not returning the cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

so I have been using this plugin for working with cookies for a bit and for some reason when i set a cookie it shows up in my browser's cookies list but when I go and dig it up it says that the cookie doesn't exist.

code for setting the cookie on muggy8.x10.mx/mmc/user/spicific-user.html

```
$.cookie('JSONdata', "muggy8@gmail.com.json", { expires: 7 });
```

the code for getting the cookie on my.matrixcomposer.tk (which provides a frame which contains muggy8.x10.mx/mmc in it)

```
var json = $.cookie('JSONdata');
```

when I go and upll up the cookie called JSONdata, it returns undefined.

thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you check request to the server? Does it contain the cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting cookie using path:

```
$.cookie('JSONdata', "muggy8@gmail.com.json", { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access cookies from another domain. The Javascript on my.matrixcomposer.tk can only see cookies set on that domain (or parent matrixcomposer.tk domain). Even if you have the iframe in there for another site, that doesn't override the security of the cookie's domain. Javascript running on one domain cannot directly access the cookies for another domain, even if there is content in the page from that other domain.

Comment: i actually tried it on the original site where everything is on the same domain and even then it didn't work.